# CSS height making scrollbar go below the page/screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

height 100vh pushes scroll bar under the screen/page

but

[image]

it seems height 82.5vh is perfect size

how can I ensure that height fits the screen/page? or calculate which height will fit the screen in this case 82.5vh?

Comment: The answer is probably to use `calc()`, but without a working example of your code, we have no way to provide a decent answer.

Comment: Please instead of pictures, provide a [minimal reproductible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: why -1? a comment would be useful..

Comment: You can try 100% instead, but the reason for the problem is the topbar; 100vh is the entire Viewport Height, and the available space is less than that. The simplest way to make stuff fill up available space is to use flexbox for the entire layout.

Comment: The negative votes are probably because you haven't included a code example of the problem, which is pretty essential for this sort of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the height of the top element, for example if it is `200px` you can then set :
`height: calc(100vh - 200px)` to the scrollable container. Just make sure you include any eventual margin in the calc.

Comment: Just a question: on mobile devices, Chrome acts differently when scrolling down the page, increasing the height of the WebView (removing the url bar). If the user scrolls up again, it shows the URL bar, making the page scrollable again. How can I avoid this and make a div fill the page?